# Upgrading from Rails 3.1 to 3.2 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading a Rails app from 3.1 to 3.2
It uses gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' with gem 'less'.

I'm getting an error trying to launch the thin server.

Now I'm getting this error.  It says "no such file" even though I have that file in my app:

```
LoadError in Home#index

Showing    /Users/burtondav/sites/requestsys/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #20 raised:

no such file to load -- less
  (in   /Users/burtondav/sites/requestsys/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
Extracted source (around line #20):

17:       }
18:   </style>
19: 
20:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
21: 
22:   <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
23:   <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
```

Is there something wrong with the less gem?

Thanks!!

UPDATE

I re-installed gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'.  Now I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined
(in     /Users/burtondav/sites/requestsys/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
```

I found this answer about less.js ->

https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/906

But, I'm using   gem 'less-rails'

Could this be a know problem that is fixed in less.js and not the less-rails gem?

UPDATE 2

I found this

"in sprite.less i changed background-image: url("@{iconSpritePath}"); and background-image: url("@{iconWhiteSpritePath}");

adding the " " and the { } got rid of the errors.."

But, that's not rails.

My paths are:

```
// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
```

UPDATE 3

I found another answer - upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3  .  I'm using ruby 1.9.2p290

But, I'm nervous doing that.  Should I be nervous?  Would my app still run on Heroku?

I'm going to open a new question - the title for this one is now incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember having a problem like this. Maybe try less-rails instead of less. I have the following:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'less-rails'
```

Also make sure you have (or some other javascript interpreter).

```
  gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2', :platforms => :ruby
```

uncommented in your Gemfile. It almost looks like you're not able to compile your assets which

Comment: I'm getting this:  /Users/burtondav/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/less-rails-1.0.0/lib/less-rails.rb:11:in `<module:Plugin>': uninitialized constant Less::Plugin::RAILS_ROOT (NameError)

Comment: If you have those gems defined in the assets group maybe try moving them out of there. Can you past the full stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry - but, how do I get a "stacktrace"?

Comment: Can you add your Gemfile contents?

Comment: I added my gemifle to the question.